# Javaのバージョン互換性確認方法

Tags: java

Java1.4で作成したWebアプリをJava8でコンパイルしなおし、動かそうとしています。

Javaのバージョンが上がると様々な互換性の問題が発生するのでその確認方法をどうとればよいのかご教示いただきたいです
。
例えばJava1.5でenumが予約語になったのでソース上にenumという変数が含まれていればJava1.4ではコンパイルが通りますが、Java1.8ではエラーとなります。
コンパイルエラー箇所に関してはコンパイルをかければ拾えるのでよいのですが、コンパイルエラーとならず振る舞いに差分がある場合はどのように検出すべきでしょうか。

Java1.4→8なので
1.4 → 5
5 → 6
6 → 7
7 → 8 （http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/jp/java/javase/overview/8-compatibility-guide-2156366-ja.html#A999198）

それぞれの互換性に関するドキュメントを確認すればよいのかと考えていますが、
該当するすべてのドキュメントを探しきれませんでした。

Java1.4→8へのマイグレーションガイド等があればよいのですが。。。
ご存知でしたら教えてください。

Answer (score 4):

> それぞれの互換性に関するドキュメント

英語版であればOracleのサイトに全て残っています：

- 7 → 8: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/jp/java/javase/8-compatibility-guide-2156366.html
- 6 → 7: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-417013.html
- 5.0 → 6: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-137541.html
- 1.4.2 → 5.0: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-137462.html
- 1.4.1 → 1.4.2: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-142878.html
- 1.4.0 → 1.4.1: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-j2se1-140308.html

---

> Java1.4→8へのマイグレーションガイド等があればよいのですが。。。

世代が恐ろしく離れているため（2002→2014年!）、確認しながらマイグレーションを進める以外にないと思われます...